# [DATABRICKS]how to store SQ L query result data to local disk?

Tags: python, azure-databricks

I am a newbie to data bricks and trying to write results into the excel/ CSV file using the below command but getting `DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_csv'` errors while executing.

I am using a notebook to execute my SQL queries and now want to store results in the CSV or excel file

```
%python

df =spark.sql ("""select * from customer""")
```

and now I want to store the query results in the excel/csv file.I have tried the below code but it's not working

```
df.coalesce(1).write.option("header","true").option("sep",",").mode("overwrite").csv("file:///C:/New folder/mycsv.csv")
```

AND

```
df.write.option("header", "true").csv("file:///C:/New folder/mycsv.csv")
```

Comment: have you tried `df.to_csv`?

Comment: Wait df is a pandas dataframe right?

Comment: df.to_csv its not working

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"

Comment: DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Comment: Then something's gone wrong, because it definitely should.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: The `df` here is a pyspark Dataframe. Hence the error `DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_csv'`

Comment: I know but how to resolve it that's the main question

Comment: You can use `pandas_df = df.toPandas()`. Then to_csv will work

Comment: Do you have working solution?